# Regex for Money validation

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need regex to validate money.

0.00 and 0 cannot be allowed,
0.01 can be allowed and onwards can be allowed
5.00 can be allowed,
5.01 can be allowed,
5.25 can be allowed

My regex `^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$`
 but this validates 0.00

Comment: Did you try doing this for yourself at all?  People on SO like to see the effort.

Comment: @JayRiggs ^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$. This is what i have done. But this validates 0.00.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!0.00|0$)\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

Try this.This will not validate 0.00 and 0.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/29